# Add exception in log4j patterlayout in JSON format

Tags: java, log4j

I want to log in JSON. I have the following `log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.rootCategory=ALL,console
log4j.logger.com.demo.package=ALL,console
log4j.additivity.com.demo.package=false
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.immediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.console.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.conversionPattern={"debug_level":"%p","debug_timestamp":"%d{ISO8601}","debug_thread":"%t","debug_file":"%F","debug_line":"%L","debug_message":"%m"}%n
```

My log statements are like this:

```
log.error("SocketTimeoutException while fetching log:", e);
```

But this only logs the message in `debug_message` key i.e. `SocketTimeoutException while fetching log:` and the exception stacktrace is logged in a separate line outside the json.

How can I make the exception part of the Pattern.